# Hexchat IRC Client over http / https?

Tags: security, proxy, http, tunnel, irc

Is there a way you can use an IRC Client such as hexchat for ports 80/443 out to connect into freenode for example?

I understand that http://webchat.freenode.net/ has a gateway into IRC over port 80 that then connects into 6667 through a host.

Is there a gateway or setup I can connect to from hexchat, on port 80/443 that will give me a connection into an IRC Channel on 6667?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, simply since that's not how it works.

"Webchat.freenode.net" is actually an instance of qwebirc - which is a *irc client* with some special settings that let it pass  on user information to the server.

qwebirc does not act as a proxy (or in IRC parlence) a bouncer, and uses clever things like http and websockets. Hexchat does not speak HTTP.

So, no, it will not work. Certainly not as a way to get around naive protocol or port blocks. Its like asking someone who speaks only Chinese directions in esperanto.

Comment: Bummer, but this seems like the right answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN however run your own service like webchat, if you have your own (virtual private?) server on the Internet.

One such solution is - Convos:

> Convos is the simplest way to use IRC. It is always online, and
>   accessible to your web browser, both on desktop and mobile. Run it on
>   your home server, or cloud service easily. It can be deployed to
>   Docker-based cloud services, or you can just run it as a normal
>   Mojolicious application.
>
> Learn more about how to install and configure Convos in the guides or
>   just run the two commands below to install and start Convos:

```
$ curl https://convos.by/install.sh | sh -
$ ./convos/script/convos daemon
```